# jquery removing input type image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know what the issue with these scripts are pretty much what I'm trying to do is have an input removed when you click it. It's a type image input so you can't use CSS so I've tried with java and it doesn't seem to work

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<body>
<article>
<div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="a.js"></script>

<img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
<div id="button1"><a href="#button1" id="w"><input class="do-hide" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')" type="image"     src="button.png" /></div>
<div id="1button2"><a href="#button2" id="b"><input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button2" src="button1.png" /></a></div>
<div id="1button3"><a href="#button3" id="c"><input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button3" src="button3.png" /></a></div>
<div id="1button4"><a href="#button4" id="d"><input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button4" src="button5.png" /></a></div>
<div id="1button5"><a href="#button5" id="e"><input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button5" src="button4.png" /></a></div>
</div> 
</article>
</body>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click','a.do-hide',function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $(href).hide();
});
```

CSS

```
a { display:block; }

input.hideable{
display:block;
border:1px solid #AAA;
}

.hideable:target {
display:none;
}

body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; background-image: url("b.png"); }
body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666a73; }
article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
#button1 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
top: 500px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#button1:hover {
width: 270px;
height: 60px;
}
#w:target {
display: none;
}
#button2 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 600px;
top: 500px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#button2:hover {
width: 270px;
height: 60px;
}
#b:target {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

#button3 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 900px;
top: 500px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#button3:hover {
width: 270px;
height: 60px;
}
#c:target {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

#button4 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 1200px;
top: 500px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#button4:hover {
width: 270px;
height: 60px;
}
#d:target {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

#button5 {
height: 50px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 1500px;
top: 500px;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#button5:hover {
width: 270px;
height: 60px;
}
#e:target {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

img {
position: absolute; 
left: 520px;
top: 100px;
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. `a.do-hide` looks for an `<a>` element with a class of `do-hide`. Instead you need to find the `.do-hide` as a *child* of an `<a>`, so you need a space between the selectors. Then you can use `$(this).hide()` to hide the element. Try this:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a .do-hide', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
<div id="button1">
  <a href="#button1" id="w">
    <input class="do-hide" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')" type="image" src="button.png" />
</div>
<div id="1button2">
  <a href="#button2" id="b">
    <input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button2" src="button1.png" />
  </a>
</div>
<div id="1button3">
  <a href="#button3" id="c">
    <input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button3" src="button3.png" />
  </a>
</div>
<div id="1button4">
  <a href="#button4" id="d">
    <input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button4" src="button5.png" />
  </a>
</div>
<div id="1button5">
  <a href="#button5" id="e">
    <input class="do-hide" type="image" id="button5" src="button4.png" />
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason, I copied the code

Comment: Check the console for errors. As you can see above, it should work fine.

Comment: Here a fiddle link do you see any issue? Edit: Sorry wrong link https://jsfiddle.net/Gmanc2/3s1gztso/

Comment: Heres the colab link https://jsfiddle.net/Gmanc2/3s1gztso/#&togetherjs=RidheDzxQo

Comment: The code in the fiddle is working - the elements are being hidden.

Comment: So it does. Any I Idea why this wouldn't work on a hosted site?

Comment: I'm afraid not. All I can suggest is that you check the console for any errors elsewhere in the code

Comment: Hmm this is very odd the code in that fiddle is the only code I have on my webpage but for some reason it doenst work. would you mind checking here? http://terminusprison.com/vote/

Comment: Ah - you need to put the jQuery code in a document ready handler (`$(function() { /* code here */ })`) or you need to put the `<script>` with `a.js` in it just before the `</body>` tag. Your code right now is attaching the event handlers to elements that don't exist yet

Comment: ($(function() { $('body').on('click', 'a .do-hide', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
}); }))  
Like so?

Comment: You don't need to outer brackets. Here's a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/yu1j2p31/

Comment: Thank you so much my apologies I am unfamiliar with JS mostly just lua and css haha.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the input you could add this

```
$(".do-hide").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work either It works in a jsfiddle but not in chrome or ie any ideas?